# can't find executable cap for gem capistrano

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano

Although I `bundle install` without any issue, and I do have Capistrano in Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '3.4.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2'
  gem 'capistrano-slackify', require: false
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

but, if I try to `bundle exec cap deploy` I get error:

```
/Users/samir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:462:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable cap for gem capistrano. capistrano is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
        from /Users/samir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:493:in `block in replace_bin_path'
        from /Users/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
        from /Users/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        from /Users/samir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you run Capistrano installation already? (Run `bundle exec cap install`, see ["Capify" your project](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#capify-your-project).) I would also expect that you'd have to specify the environment where to deploy to, something like `bundle exec cap staging deploy`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I had to explicitly set development group, as `bundle install --with development`, and then it worked..